# CSS display elements with other heights NOT inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I display elements with other heights and this same widths in nice way?

Here is my fiddle: jsfiddle.net/54Tg6/

Here I have example of inline display but I want to put each box only 5px space between box over. How can I do it ?

Comment: You mean something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/54Tg6/1/

Comment: No, I want to put each 5px under one over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a grid layout library such as [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or better [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html).

Isotope require a one-time purchase for a commercial license but free for non-commercial, personal, or open source projects and applications

In the other hand, Masonry is released under the MIT License.